# Crash when app relaunched too quickly

Tags: ios

So here is the most vague question you will probably ever see. I can't give too much detail since it's a sensitive app for a client.

Essentially, my app cannot run in the background. When I close the app by pressing the close button it starts a close sequence which takes a few seconds. If I start the app again too soon, everything in the app starts up as you would expect it to normally, except the view is stuck on the Default.png image. Also, after a short amount of time the app crashes and the logs reveal that the application took too long to shut down and so iOS killed it (it thinks its the same application as before).

Is there a solution to this?

If you need further details, please ask and I will answer what I can.

Thanks!

Comment: You probably shouldn't start an SO question with "most vague question you will probably ever see"

Comment: Probably not no, but I don't want to waste peoples time.

Comment: Does it happen in the simulator? My technique on solving this kind of problem is to sprinkle my code with log messages, then see what the last one is when it hangs, then add more etc. Others use lldb or even instruements. It just takes work - no magic solution for you.

Comment: Unfortunately I am working with an external accessory and so cannot test using the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem I often run into(assuming we have the same problem). Deploy your app from Xcode, then hit the "stop" button. Then you can try launching and relaunching. I'm not exactly sure what causes this but it seems Xcode doesn't like when you exit and renter an app that is still running in the debugger.